# Changing default lines in Sweave

Tags: r, rstudio, sweave

Whenever I open a new RSweave file I get the following code as a default:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}




\end{document}
```

When I write Sweave files I always add the same lines (title, date, sections...). I wonder if I could save some time changing this so that every time I open a Sweave tab I have some headstart.

Comment: In Rstudio, as far as I know, only rmarkdown files allow for templating (e.g. see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html)). An alternative would be to prepare template, open it and use Save as to make a new document.

Comment: You can also have project templates:  https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_project_templates.html.  They might be overkill for this though.